# How to loop through a selected item(languages) using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: html, forms

I accepted a list of languages as a HTTP request and I am seeing how I can loop this over to an Azure logic app. But before I do that, I am wondering how to loop through selected languages to be processed to an Azure logic app?

For example, if the user selected Spanish, how would I process 'Spanish' and send that to my Azure logic app?

Here is my HTML file I created with check boxes of all the languages:

Language.html:

```
<h2>Check Box</h2>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="english"> English<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="spanish"> Spanish <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="vietnamese"> Vietnamese<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="somali"> Somali <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="chinese"> Chinese <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="amharic"> Amharic <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="korean"> Korean <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="russian"> Russian <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="tagalog"> Tagalog <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="arabic"> Arabic <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="khmer"> Khmer <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="thai"> Thai <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="lao"> Lao <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="japanese"> Japanese <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="deutsch"> Deutsche <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Same name, type="radio" and it is "Deutsch" not "Deutsche" unless you add "Sprache"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE after clarification**

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const url = new URL("https://api.videoindexer.ai/location/Accounts/accountId/Videos/videoId/Index?language=...&reTranslate=...&includeStreamingUrls=...&accessToken=...");
  const language = document.getElementById("language").value;
  url.searchParams.set("language",language)
  console.log(url); // change to a fetch or similar
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

#chosen {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="language" id="language">
    <option value="en-GB">Please select language (Default en-GB</option> 
    <option value="sr-Cyrl-RS">Serbian (Cyrillic)</option>
    <option value="sr-Latn-RS">Serbian (Latin)</option>
    <option value="bs-Latn">Bosnian</option>
    <option value="zh-Hans">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
    <option value="zh-Hant">Chinese (Traditional)</option>
    <option value="fil-PH">Filipino</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="en-FJ">Fijian</option>
    <option value="en-AU">English Australia</option>
    <option value="en-WS">Samoan</option>
    <option value="en-US">English United States</option>
    <option value="el-GR">Greek</option>
    <option value="es-ES">Spanish</option>
    <option value="et-EE">Estonian</option>
    <option value="fa-IR">Persian</option>
    <option value="fi-FI">Finnish</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">French</option>
    <option value="fr-HT">Haitian</option>
    <option value="af-ZA">Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="ar-SY">Arabic Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="ar-EG">Arabic Egypt</option>
    <option value="da-DK">Danish</option>
    <option value="de-DE">German</option>
    <option value="bg-BG">Bulgarian</option>
    <option value="bn-BD">Bangla</option>
    <option value="mg-MG">Malagasy</option>
    <option value="ms-MY">Malay</option>
    <option value="mt-MT">Maltese</option>
    <option value="ca-ES">Catalan</option>
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech</option>
    <option value="nl-NL">Dutch</option>
    <option value="nb-NO">Norwegian</option>
    <option value="id-ID">Indonesian</option>
    <option value="it-IT">Italian</option>
    <option value="lt-LT">Lithuanian</option>
    <option value="lv-LV">Latvian</option>
    <option value="ja-JP">Japanese</option>
    <option value="ur-PK">Urdu</option>
    <option value="uk-UA">Ukrainian</option>
    <option value="hi-IN">Hindi</option>
    <option value="he-IL">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="hu-HU">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="hr-HR">Croatian</option>
    <option value="ko-KR">Korean</option>
    <option value="vi-VN">Vietnamese</option>
    <option value="tr-TR">Turkish</option>
    <option value="ta-IN">Tamil</option>
    <option value="th-TH">Thai</option>
    <option value="to-TO">Tongan</option>
    <option value="ru-RU">Russian</option>
    <option value="ro-RO">Romanian</option>
    <option value="pt-BR">Portuguese</option>
    <option value="pl-PL">Polish</option>
    <option value="sv-SE">Swedish</option>
    <option value="sw-KE">Kiswahili</option>
    <option value="sl-SI">Slovenian</option>
    <option value="sk-SK">Slovak</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can map them using document.querySelectorAll:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.name && e.target.name === "language")
    document.getElementById("chosen").textContent = [...this.querySelectorAll("[name=language]:checked")].map(chk => chk.value).join(", ");
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

#chosen {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<h2>Check Box</h2>

<span id="chosen"></span>

<form>
  <ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="english"> English</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="spanish"> Spanish</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="vietnamese"> Vietnamese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="somali"> Somali</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="chinese"> Chinese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="amharic"> Amharic</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="korean"> Korean</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="russian"> Russian</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="tagalog"> Tagalog</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="arabic"> Arabic</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="khmer"> Khmer</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="thai"> Thai</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="lao"> Lao</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="japanese"> Japanese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="deutsch"> Deutsch</label></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: what I meant was, say for example the user chooses Spanish and clicks ‘submit’. How can Spanish be processed into this api https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index as a language parameter? So that my azure logic app knows the language the user chose is Spanish.

Comment: Please see update. I changed the checkboxes to a select since you can only use one language. Also I took the languages from https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index

Comment: I will give it a try and will get back if I have any queries. Thank you for the help.

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question: but if I want to run this locally on my machine, do you recommend what IDE I could use to run the HTML,Jquery,CSS? Or is notepad++ enough?

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep `name` attribute same , as the variable name in which `data/value` would be saved when user checks any checkbox

```
<h2>Check Box</h2>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="english"> English<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="spanish"> Spanish <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="vietnamese"> Vietnamese<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="somali"> Somali <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="chinese"> Chinese <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="amharic"> Amharic <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="korean"> Korean <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="russian"> Russian <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="tagalog"> Tagalog <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="arabic"> Arabic <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="khmer"> Khmer <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="thai"> Thai <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="lao"> Lao <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="japanese"> Japanese <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="language" value="deutsche"> Deutsche <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Or better. make it a radio unless they can choose more than one language

Comment: And also use labels for your inputs. And don't use <br> for creating a list.

Comment: Question: So how can I loop through selected languages rather than send one language to be processed?